# What do these character codes mean, is my file corrupt?

Tags: php, vim, unicode

I'm editing a file in vim and my function looks like this:

```
function arrForeignCharacterMapping()
 {
     return array(
         '<8a>'=>'S', '<9a>'=>'s', 'Ð'=>'Dj','<8e>'=>'Z', '<9e>'=>'z', 'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A',
         'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E', 'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I',
         'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U', 'Ú'=>'U',
         'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss','à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a',
         'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c', 'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i',
         'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o', 'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u',
         'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b', 'ÿ'=>'y', '<83>'=>'f'
     );
 }
```

This is roughly about translating accented characters etc into their "basic" versions.  What are the `<8a>` etc though?  They're single characters in vim (i.e. shown in a grey colour and the cursor "skips" over them in one movement.

I've tried googling them but it's tricky for obvious reasons.  If it's "correct", can someone give me a link that correlates these codes with the unicode characters they represent?

Thanks!

Comment: I think they could be hexadecimal representative. Like 0x8a could be S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can google "unicode character map", its pretty common so I'm sure you will find many tools and one you would like.

this was one of the first results for me: http://charmap.online-toolz.com/tools/character-map.php

look at the unicode character value, as such:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, always nice to have a "simple" problem for a change.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you are looking for this. In vim

```
echo char2nr('ý',1)
```

will print `253`